# Visual Studio 2012: Switch from debug to realease easily

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We are using about 5 projects that connects together via web calls.

Right now, the Uris for the web calls are saved in web.config file via  tags.

```
<add key="ProductsAPIURL" value="http://192.168.1.4:5000" />
```

When we are in debug mode, we change in all the projects the uris of the api calls to match localhost ports.

When moving it into production, we change them back.

Is there any other way of easily switching from Debug to Release without having to manually change the settings every time? (something like creating a visual studio profile which remembers all these settings)

Comment: Use two settings and #if DEBUG in code

Comment: Agree, but i need to have Debug mode (while coding), Testing mode (while testing internally) and Release mode (when is released)

Comment: That is a new question: How do I deploy settings to production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration transforms will do this for you allowing you to have any number of configuration that you can switch between in seconds

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This is a good solution for the "additional deployment question".

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Debug and Release configs. You will have the following files:

```
Web.config
Web.Debug.Config
Web.Release.Config
```

You could define a connectionstring in `Web.config` and override it in `Web.Release.Config`:

`Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConString" connectionString="Data Source=." />
</connectionStrings>
```

`Web.Release.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConString" connectionString="Data Source=different" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Or you could the use the preprocessor directive  `#if`.

```
#if DEBUG
    myConString = "Data Source=."
#else
    myConString = "Data Source=different"
#endif
```

Comment: Is there a convention in Visual Studio to know that it needs to use `Web.Debug.Config` while i am in debugging and  `Web.Release.Config` when the project is compiled in release mode?

Comment: Building the solution on `Debug` will cause it use the `Web.Debug.config`, building the solution in `Release` will cause it use the `Web.Release.config`. (You can configure it in visual studio or a build config)